# How to validate date of birth that should be less than 18 years old in Codeigneter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I used so many stuff but I am unable to validate date of birth should be less than 18 years old

```
<?php echo form_error('DOB'); ?>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
  Date Of Birth
</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="text"  class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="DOB" placeholder="Date Of Birth" value="<?php echo set_value('DOB'); ?>"  >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use a callback for this. Example:

```
public function your_form_page()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    // this part is when you set your validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('DOM', 'Date of Birth', 'trim|required||callback_validate_age');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_age','Member is not valid!');
}

// you need to add this on the controller, this will be the custom validation
public function validate_age($age) {
    $dob = new DateTime($age);
    $now = new DateTime();
    return ($now->diff($dob)->y > 18) ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: where to call validate_age($age) and how to pass value i am new in codeignetor

Comment: @user3342546 what's important is you have to put this on your code (controller), you're using validation of codeigniter right?

Comment: ya sir i need where i put this code

Comment: @user3342546 in your controller you need to add the rules inside the controller

Comment: thanks .... nice working and thanks for callback procedure